# SSAS Multidimensional - Table Value Function as a Query for Partition

Tags: ssas, sql-server-2014

> @GregGalloway was able to answer the question I should have asked. I am adding a more concise question here, while maintaining the original lengthy text
>
> How do I use a table valued function as the query for a partition, when the function is in separate database from my fact and referenced dimensions?

Overview: I am building a SSAS multidimensional cube that is built off of a single fact table in our application's data warehouse, and want to use the result set from a table valued function as my fact table's partition query. We are using SQL Server (and SSAS) 2014

Condition: For each environment (Dev,Tst,Prd) there are 2 separate databases on the same server, one for the application data warehouse `[DW_App]`, the other for custom objects `[DW_Custom]`. I cannot create any objects in `[DW_App]`, but have a lot of freedom in `[DW_Custom]`

Background info: I have not been able to find much information on using a TVF and partitions in this way. My thinking is that it will help streamline future development by giving me a single place to update the SQL if/when I modify the fact table.

So in testing out my crazy idea of using a TVF as the query for my partitions I have run into a bit of a conundrum. I am able to use my TVF when I explicitly state the Database in my FROM clause.

`SELECT * FROM [DW_Custom].[dbo].[CubePartition](@StartDate, @EndDate)`

However, that will not work, because the cube will be deployed in multiple environments before production, and it needs to point to different DBs for each. So I tried adding a new data source, setting my partition query to point to the new data source, and then remove the database name. IE:

`SELECT * FROM [dbo].[CubePartition](@StartDate, @EndDate)`

I get an error that

> The SQL syntax is not valid. The relational database returned the following error message: Deferred prepare could not be completed. Invalid object name 'dbo.CubePartition'

If I click through this error and the subsequent warnings about the cube not being able to process if I continue I am able to build and deploy the cube. However I cannot process it, because I get an error that one of my dimensions does not exist.
Looking into the query that was generated and it is clear that it is querying my dimensions as well as fact, which do not exist inside of '[DW_Custom]' which explains that error perfectly fine.

So I guess 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to query another DB (on the same server) from inside of an SSAS partition query?
2. If not, is there any way I can use a variable as the database name in the query, and update that variable based on the project configuration (Dev,Tst,Prd)

Bonus question: Is the reason that I can not find much about doing it this way because it is an obviously bad idea that I am overlooking, and if so why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a second SSAS Data Source pointing to the DW_Custom database (or whatever it's called in the particular environment you're deploying to)? Then when you deploy from Dev to Prod, you need only change that connection string. When you create your partitions, then specify the DW_Custom data source and then specify the query without database name:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[CubePartition](@StartDate, @EndDate)
```

As long as the query plan for that table-valued function is efficient compared to a plain SELECT statement, then I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have tried that, and I get an error that: SQL Syntax is not Valid: Deferred prepare could not be completed. I just accepted the error and build/deployed the solution, which works. However, Processing fails, I receive an error that there is an Invalid Object Name for my fact table. I will update my question with this new information.

Comment: @BrandonMcClure, I assume the query you used is SELECT * FROM [dbo].[CubePartition]('1/1/2015', '1/31/2015') (no parameters in the query)?

Comment: @BrandonMcClure, do you have a reference dimension or something that would require a join during fact processing? In the processing dialog, what's the SQL query which produces an error? Can you tell why it's not valid? Having a second data source pointed at Initial Catalog=DW_Custom should work.

Comment: It is trying to query some of the dimensions, which of course are not in DW_Custom. And the query is SELECT * FROM [dbo].[CUBEPARTITION]('1/1/2015',1/31/2015')

Comment: @BrandonMcClure, which dimensions? Are they reference dimensions or something that require a join? Can you create a view in DW_Custom so those queries succeed?

Comment: They are reference dimensions! So you are saying to try creating views in DW_Custom which just point to the corresponding table in DW_App? That sounds like a great idea, I will give it a shot tomorrow morning and let you know how it turns out.

Comment: My cube had reference dimensions. Creating views in `DW_Custom` that reference the referenced dimension objects in `DW_App` worked! Thanks @GregGalloway